# JSON parsing escaped string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

Why dosen't JSON.parse parse this:

```
{
    "things1": "[{\"stuff1\":\"data1\"}]"
}
```

When I enter this

```
JSON.parse('{ "things1": "[{\"stuff1\":\"data1\"}]" }')
```

I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
```

It seems `"[{\"stuff1\":\"data1\"}]"` is properly escaped.

Comment: Well, it's not a valid json. `things1` attribute points to a string that starts with `[{` and interrupts then. Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having escaping issues, specifically because you have nested strings.  You need to double escape the `\"` bits using `\\"`.

Edited: Meant to add a sample.

`JSON.parse('{ "things1": "[{\\"stuff1\\":\\"data1\\"}]" }');`