# Construct nested escaped JSON string for JSON.parse() recursive retreival

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, recursion

The server returns me a JSON string like this:

```
{"payload":{"data":"{\"notification_type\":\"{\"type1\":\"{\"type2\":\"type2 value\"}\"}\"}"}}
```

This string, as I understand, cannot be parsed with JSON.parse() API because the nested JSON strings within the string should be properly escaped. If the string is not properly escaped I get the below error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 22
```

So, the string should be properly escaped respecting the nested nature like below so that JSON.parse() can process it:

```js
var properString = "{\"payload\":{\"data\":\"{\\\"notification_type\\\":\\\"{\\\\\\\"InternalKey\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"InternalValue\\\\\\\"}\\\"}\"}}";
console.log("Proper String = ");
console.log(properString);
var firstLevelObject = JSON.parse(properString);
console.log("First Level Object = ");
console.log(firstLevelObject);
var secondLevelObject = JSON.parse (firstLevelObject.payload.data);
console.log("Second Level Object = ");
console.log(secondLevelObject);
var thirdLevelObject = JSON.parse(secondLevelObject.notification_type);
console.log("Third Level Object = ");
console.log(thirdLevelObject);
```

This is how google chrome's console outputs the same:
[image]

I however am unable to convert the improper string from server to properly escaped string as defined in the variable `properString` so that the JSON is properly constructed which can be traversable. How can the string be converted with proper escape characters?

Reference sources:
I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29464304/260665) answer to understand how nested escape characters should be added, but the answer does not state how conversion can be done.

Comment: First question: can you push back on the one who maintains the server code?  Ideally you would never receive data like this!  (I know, I know!)

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Yes bad code from server end, it will take months if not years to reach the team and convince them of this error. Not possible :(

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the JSON string what you get is not exactly right. It's not a right JSON syntax in the nested JSON String. But you can rebuilt it to a correct JSON syntax string via regular expression or native JS.

```js
var obj = '{"payload":{"data":"{\"notification_type\":\"{\"type1\":\"{\"type2\":\"type2 value\"}\"}\"}"}}';
var payloadString = obj.substring(0, 20).concat('"}}');
obj = obj.substring(20, obj.length - 3).replace("\"{", "{").replace("}\"}", "}}").replace("}\"}", "}}").replace("\"{", "{");

var data = JSON.parse(obj);
var obj2 = JSON.parse(payloadString);

//console.log(payload);
//console.log(data);
obj2.payload.data = data;
console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but isn't it too much of hardcoding? I was looking for a generic solution.